# CRTSQLCI to create a stored procedure

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYSQLPROCEDURE1(PARM1 IN INT)
LANGUAGE SQL                            
SPECIFIC MYQ001 
BEGIN END;
```

The above is in my QSQLSRC. If I use RUNSQLSTM then program MYQ001 created. Behind the scenes CRTSQLCI, CRTCMOD and CRTPGM is used. I am unable to do it manually using these.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Regards,
Jemrug

Answer (score 1):

In truth, I don't think you can "do it yourself".  Why would you even want to?

Even if you could do it, you are missing the critical first step.  Generating the C source code that gets processed by CRTSQLCI which calls CRTCMOD and CRTPGM automatically.

For your simple proc, it looks like this

```
#include "qsys/qasqh/stdlib"                                                                          
#include "qsys/qasqh/stdio"                                                                           
#include "qsys/qasqh/string"                                                                          
#include "qsys/qasqh/decimal"                                                                         
#include "qsys/qasqh/wcstr"                                                                           
#include "qsys/qasqh/wchar"                                                                           
#include "qsys/qasqh/stddef"                                                                          
#include "qsys/qasqh/trgbuf"                                                                          
#include "qsys/qasqh/pointer"                                                                         
#include "qsys/qasqh/micommon"                                                                        
#include "qsys/qasqh/cpyblap"                                                                         
#include "qsys/qasqh/sqlproc"                                                                         
#include "qsys/qasqh/cpybytes"                                                                        
#define cpybytes _CPYBYTES                                                                            
EXEC SQL SET OPTION SQLMODE = *SQLPROC;                                                               
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;                                                                       
static struct SQLDLINK * SQLDLPTR;                                                                    
typedef _Packed struct SQLDLINK {                                                                     
    short SQL_DL_LEN;                                                                                 
    char SQL_DL_VERS[5];                                                                              
    char SQL_DL_TYPE[4];                                                                              
    char SQL_DL_URLLEN[5];                                                                            
    char pad8[8];                                                                                     
    char SQL_DL_URLCMMT[32718]; };                                                                    
static long SQLP_INT_VAR;                                                                             
static short SQLP_INT_VAR_IND;                                                                        
static char sqlcontrol;                                                                               
#define SQLnlvl_1 0x80                                                                                
#define SQLnlvl_0 0x7F                                                                                
static unsigned short SQL_JobCCSID;                                                                   
static long SQL_RETURN_CODE;                                                                          
static long long SQL_ARRAY_INDEX;                                                                     
static long SQL_ARRAY_SOURCE;                                                                         
typedef _Packed struct {                                                                              
long totalL;                                                                                          
short itemIdent;                                                                                      
VARCHAR tokens[1025];                                                                                 
 } SQLMsgT;                                                                                           
static SQLMsgT SQLMsg;                                                                                
static short SQLmsgL;                                                                                 
static char SQLmsgTxt[1025];                                                                          
void SQLGetDiagValue(long, void*);                                                                    
typedef struct {                                                                                      
long PARM1;                                                                                           
short SQLP_I1;                                                                                        
} MYSQLPROCEDURE1_T;                                                                                  
typedef struct {                                                                                      
long SQLP_OUTPUT;                                                                                     
short SQLP_I2;                                                                                        
} SQL_RETURN_T;                                                                                       
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;                                                                         
static void SQLPROC_PARM_DEFAULT(MYSQLPROCEDURE1_T*);                                                 
/*----------------------------------*/                                                                
static int SQLPROCH(const char *);                                                                    
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;                                                                       
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {                                                                   
short * SQLP_IND;                                                                                     
short SQLP_IND0 = 0;                                                                                  
long SQLCODE;                                                                                         
char SQLSTATE[5];                                                                                     
long sqlcode_sav;                                                                                     
char sqlstate_sav[5];                                                                                 
short sqlp_len;                                                                                       
long long SQL_ROW_COUNT;                                                                              
long SQL_RETURN_STATUS;                                                                               
MYSQLPROCEDURE1_T MYSQLPROCEDURE1;                                                                    
MYSQLPROCEDURE1_T * MYSQLPROCEDURE1_x;                                                                
SQL_RETURN_T SQL_RETURN;                                                                              
SQL_RETURN_T * SQL_RETURN_x;                                                                          
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;                                                                         
SQLCODE = 0;                                                                                          
memset(SQLSTATE, '0', 5);                                                                             
SQL_JobCCSID = SQLRetrieveJobCCSIDOpt();                                                              
sqlcontrol = 0x00;                                                                                    
SQLP_IND = (short int *)argv[2];                                                                      
MYSQLPROCEDURE1.SQLP_I1 = *(SQLP_IND+0);                                                              
if (MYSQLPROCEDURE1.SQLP_I1 >= 0)                                                                     
MYSQLPROCEDURE1.PARM1 = * (long *) argv[1];                                                           
else MYSQLPROCEDURE1.PARM1 = 0;                                                                       
SQL_RETURN.SQLP_I2 = SQLP_NULLIND;                                                                    
SQLPROC_PARM_DEFAULT(&MYSQLPROCEDURE1);                                                               
SQLP_L2:                                                                                              
SQL_END_SQLP_L2: ;                                                                                    
SQL_END_MYSQLPROCEDURE1:                                                                              
  ;                                                                                                   
if (SQL_RETURN.SQLP_I2 < 0)                                                                           
    {                                                                                                 
    if (SQLCODE >= 0)                                                                                 
        SQL_RETURN.SQLP_OUTPUT = 0;                                                                   
    else                                                                                              
        SQL_RETURN.SQLP_OUTPUT = -1;                                                                  
    }                                                                                                 
return SQL_RETURN.SQLP_OUTPUT; }                                                                      
/*----------------------------------*/                                                                
static void SQLPROC_PARM_DEFAULT(MYSQLPROCEDURE1_T * MYSQLPROCEDURE1_TEMP) {                          
MYSQLPROCEDURE1_T * MYSQLPROCEDURE1_x;                                                                
MYSQLPROCEDURE1_x = MYSQLPROCEDURE1_TEMP;                                                             
if ((*MYSQLPROCEDURE1_x).SQLP_I1 == -5)                                                               
(*MYSQLPROCEDURE1_x).SQLP_I1 = SQLP_NULLIND;                                                          
}                                                                                                     
/*----------------------------------*/                                                                
/*----------------------------------*/                                                                
static int SQLPROCH(char SQLSTATE[5]) {                                                               
  if ((SQLSTATE[0] == '0') &&                                                                         
      ((SQLSTATE[1] >= '0') && (SQLSTATE[1] <= '2')))                                                 
    return 0;                                                                                         
  return 1;                                                                                           
}                                                                                                     
/*----------------------------------*/
```

If you're interested in the generated C source, add `DBGVIEW = *LIST` to your proc definition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYSQLPROCEDURE1(PARM1 IN INT)
LANGUAGE SQL      
SPECIFIC MYQ001 
SET OPTION DBGVIEW = *LIST, OUTPUT=*PRINT
BEGIN 
END;
```

`DBGVIEW` controls the debugging info included in compiled object, `OUTPUT=*PRINT` instructs the system to keep the spool files generated by the CRTSQLCI and CRTCMOD commands around.

20 years ago or so, if you wanted to debug an SQL stored proc or UDF, you were looking at the generated C code to do it.  I for one was very happy to see IBM add `DBGVIEW = *SOURCE` so you could debug the actual SQL statements.

Comment: The reason I want to do it manually is , when the program its creates (MYQ001) I want to put "VERSION1" in associated space entry of the compiled program. Is it possible?

Comment: @jemrug check out the `COMPILEOPT` clause of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.  That should allow you to pass along options to the `CRTCMOD` (?) command.  But I've never tried it.

Comment: manual "The options CLOSQLCSR, CNULRQD, CNULIGN, COMPILEOPT, NAMING, and SQLCA are not allowed in the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.  The thing is when I use CRTSQLCI with *NOGEN it creates the 'C' source , but not like RUNSQLSTM does , so compile fails.  So I use this generated source for input for CRTCMOD , fails with , CZM0166, CZM0059 and CZM0046. arrgh...