# CRTSQLCI v RUNSQLSTM

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I am running this on OS 7.4.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYSQLPROCEDURE1(PARM1 IN INT)    
LANGUAGE SQL                                            
SPECIFIC MYQ001                                        
BEGIN                                                    
END;
```

If I run that using 'RUNSQLSTM' the code is compiled and run and a Program MYQ001 is created with spool files of CRTSQLCI and CRTCMOD with no errors.

As soon as i do it manually using CRTSQLCI with *NOGEN , this gives me a code :-

CRTSQLCI OBJ(MYLIB/MYQ001) SRCFILE(MYLIB/QSQLSRC) SRCMBR(MYQ001) COMMIT(*NONE) OPTION(*NOGEN) CLOSQLCSR(*ENDMOD) TOSRCFILE(QTEMP/QCSRC)

When I try and feed the code generated in QTEMP/QCSRC by the above to create the module:-

```
 CRTSQLCI OBJ(MYLIB/MYQ001) SRCFILE(QTEMP/QCSRC) SRCMBR(MYQ001) COMMIT(*NONE) OBJTYPE        
 (*MODULE)  OUTPUT(*PRINT)
 CLOSQLCSR(*ENDMOD) TOSRCFILE(QTEMP/QMODSRC)
```

I get a "SQL precompile failed."

```
SQL0011  30      58  Position 1 Comment not closed.                         
SQL5008  30      57  Position 11 Right parenthesis or right brace not found.
SQL0011  30      58  Position 1 Comment not closed.                         
SQL0053  10          No SQL statements found.
```

Why does it all work using RUNSQLSTM but not CRTSQLCI?

Would appreciate any help to resolve, even if its a case to say , its not possible this way?

Regards,
JemRug

Comment: I don't think that's possible, like Charles answered to your first question. Has the version info to be in the associated space ? Maybe you could store it the source file name with [QLICOBJD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/qlicobjd.htm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CRTSQLCI to create a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472748/crtsqlci-to-create-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Please don't repeatedly ask the same question.  You can always add additional details to your original.

Comment: @nfgl  I wanted to put the info in the associated space. Charles I didn't know I could go back and ask more questions on the original post as no one replied. I wanted to know CRTSQLI creates the pre-compiler code but why it does not compile it?

Comment: @Charles I wanted to know why it does not compile the code if it was the command(pre-compiler)  that generated the code. What is RUNSQLSTM doing different at the binding stage? To get a better understanding.

Comment: @nfgl I can't use QLICOBJD its all being used for other info, hence I need want put it in the associated space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion. It seems you think that RUNSQLSTM is calling CRTSQLCI and CRTCMOD, and maybe even CRTSRVPGM, and that CRTSQLCI is simply running against the SQL source that you typed into RUNSQLSTM. Every bit of this is wrong.

What these programs do:

RUNSQLSTM - SQL client passes SQL statements to the DB2 for i database for interpretation and execution.

CRTSQLCI - C precompiler that turns embedded SQL code into native C code. This calls one of the C compilers to produce a module or a program object.

CRTCMOD - C compiler that produces a module. This one has no SQL Precompiler.

CRTSRVPGM - Linker that ingests modules to build a service program.

Note that while CRTSQLCI turns embedded SQL into native C code, the SQL you type into RUNSQLSTM is not formatted correctly for CRTSQLCI to turn it into native C code. There is an entire other manual that tells you how to write C code with embedded SQL. That is what CRTSQLCI needs. It does not look at all like standalone SQL statements. [Coding SQL Statements in C and C++ Applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=programming-coding-sql-statements-in-c-c-applications)

So what is happening? Why is it that every SQL client that can connect to DB2 for i can create and compile DB2 for i routines? Do they all have to convert the stored procedure code to C with embedded SQL and pass that to CRTSQLCI? No, none of them do. SQL clients simply pass the raw SQL to DB2 for i. The server itself knows how to generate the C code with embedded SQL that is passed to the precompiler. The precompiler then turns the embedded sql statements into native C code and then passes the resulting source to the C compiler, and finally DB2 passes the resulting module to CRTSRVPGM to turn it into a service program. The final service program name is stored in the SQL catalog so future calls to the routine can be executed directly.

So it appears that you are missing a few steps. But if you know C, you can write a shell in C that allows you to insert virtually any SQL stored procedure you want and then compile it into a program using CRTSQLCI, then execute the resulting program object to create the service program.

Or if you know RPG, you can use that to do the same thing. But, instead of using CRTSQLCI you would use CRTSQLRPGI to create the program object.

Or, you could just use RUNSQLSTM because that will do all of this in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely unclear what CRTSQLCI has to do with your SQL code.
It's meant for something completely different.

> The Create SQL ILE C Object (CRTSQLCI) command calls the Structured Query Language (SQL) precompiler which precompiles C source containing SQL statements, produces a temporary source member, and then optionally calls the ILE C compiler to create a module, create a program, or create a service program.
> [Create SQL ILE C object (CRTSQLCI)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/cl/crtsqlci.html)

It is needed to compile C code containing embedded SQL. For example:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "sqlcli.h"
#include "sql.h"

main (int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;
  char vname[20];
  
  EXEC SQL SELECT vname INTO :vname FROM video WHERE videnum=10;
  printf("%s", vname);
}
```

In your case, it is correct to use RUNSQLSTM

> The Run SQL Statements (RUNSQLSTM) command processes a source file of Structure Query Language (SQL) statements.
> [Run SQL Statements (RUNSQLSTM)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/runsqlstm.htm)

Comment: @Vicktor, totally agree with you. But when you use RUNSQLSTM it uses CRTSQLCI and then CRTCMOD to create module, which it deletes and creates the program, hence I thought I could do the same. RUNSQLSTM creates source in QTEMP and either uses a binding directory to compiles the code (which is C with embedded SQL) .

Comment: But it does not run CRTSQLCI to generate the C code, CRTSQLCI is a C compiler with an SQL precompiler as a front end. In order to use CRTSQLCI, you need C code with embedded SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure this is a non-duplicate...but
First of all...

The output of the pre-compiler is designed to be processed by the regular complier.  So you shouldn't be using `CRTSQLCI` you should be using `CRTCMOD`.

Secondly, ensure that `QTEMP/QCSRC` doesn't exists or if it exists it has a large enough line length, from the errors you posted it seems some of the lines output by the pre-compiler may have been trucated.

Comment: Thanks @Charles, weather its CRTSQLCI with *NOGEN and the *MODULE to create CRTCMOD, the pre-compiler creates the output source, so you can't set the record length.  One thing I can say it puts a "/***$$$ " in the output source. Which looks like a comment that is not terminated properly in 'C' source. I'm not a c programmer, hence don't know how it should be terminated and you are not allowed to change the code in the pre-processor stage.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have never heard that RUNSQLSTM uses CRTSQLCI - in my opinion these are completely different things.
I can understand the choice between RUNSQLSTM and a combination of CRTQMQRY/STRQMQRY/DLTQMQRY when you need a parameterized SQL query like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE &ALIB.CLEAR_USER_QUEUE 
                    (
                      IN USER_QUEUE VARCHAR(10),
                      IN USER_QUEUE_LIBRARY VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '*LIBL',
                      IN KEY_DATA VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
                      IN KEY_ORDER CHARACTER(2) DEFAULT NULL
                    )
                  SPECIFIC &ALIB.QSQCLRUSRQ
                  LANGUAGE RPGLE
                  NOT DETERMINISTIC
                  NO SQL
                  PARAMETER STYLE SQL
                  EXTERNAL NAME &EXTNAME
                  NOT FENCED
                  PROGRAM TYPE SUB
```

And then we use a CL program containing

```
DLTQMQRY QMQRY(QTEMP/USRQCLR_P)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF2105)
CRTQMQRY QMQRY(QTEMP/USRQCLR_P) SRCFILE(&ASRC/&SRCF) SRCMBR(USRQCLR_P) REPLACE(*YES)
STRQMQRY QMQRY(QTEMP/USRQCLR_P) SETVAR(('ALIB' &ALIB) ('EXTNAME' ('''' !< &ALIB !<-
 '/USRQSQLSRV(SQL_USRQClear)''')))
DLTQMQRY QMQRY(QTEMP/USRQCLR_P)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF2105)
```

As a result, we get the opportunity to use the parameters passed from the CL program arguments to the SQL expression.

Comment: I was more looking to "Add Associated space entry" into the program when we create a SQL procedure as it ultimately creates a program type object when you use RUNSQLSTM, hence I was trying the understand what was going on in the background. Creating a procedure using RUNSQLSTM will in QTEMP create the source , which you use to CRTPGM and add the "Add Associated space entry"

Comment: Apparently I didn't understand you well enough, but the SQL statement CREATE PROCEDURE does not create a program object (an object of type *PGM). It creates a stored procedure that can only be called using SQL.
RUNSQLSTM doesn't create a procedure by itself - it's just a way to execute a SQL statement. Any expression - CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE... or whatever else you need.
As a matter of fact, it can be a rather voluminous script written in SQL, which you can execute both in interactive mode (STRSQL or in ACS), and call its execution from the program.

Comment: All this is in no way connected with the commands CRTMOD, CRTPGM and others like them, which in essence are a call to the corresponding compiler of one of the languages ​​compiled and supported by ILE (C, C ++, RPG, CL, COBOL).
SQL does not apply to compiled languages, SQL programs are not compiled into *MODULE and *PGM type objects (although SQL expressions can be included in the code of programs in ILE languages, but only as separate expressions and only as part of the code)